# How to add left border for list when it is active?

Tags: vue.js

The code below is not working for vuetify 2.0.0-beta.0 version.

.v-list__group--active {
  border-left: 2px solid blue
}

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ydYdMM?&editable=true&editors=101

Comment: You can refer above codepen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a typo in your class selector. Use `.v-list-group--active` instead of `.v-list__group--active`. See [corrected codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LKGPNx)